# File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

For any package I try to install, I get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\Mehrag>pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.certifi import where
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import contents, where
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from importlib.resources import read_text
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\resources.py", line 11, in <module>
    from typing import Iterable, Iterator, Optional, Set, Union   # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\typing.py", line 1357, in <module>
    class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
  File "C:\Users\Mehrag\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\typing.py", line 1005, in __new__
    self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

I tried to remove Python for my PC and re-installed it, did not work. Also I deleted Anaconda and also this did not solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22AttributeError%22+%22type+object+Callable+has+no+attribute+_abc_registry%22

Comment: @phd non of these posts gave a working solution. I tried everything.